# linq query from two database

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a linq query from two database, however, each time the program stops at the query point. I don't know how to debug linq using VS. Can someone help me figure it out what's wrong here? Thank you.

```
public List<Promotion> GetBroder(string source)
        {
            string _connString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DB1"];
            PromotionDataContext dc = new PromotionDataContext(_connString);
            string connString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DB2"];
            ReachDirectDataContext RDdc = new ReachDirectDataContext(connString);
            return (from b in RDdc.BrokerNos
                    from p in dc.Promotions
                    where p.Source == source && p.Broker == b.BrokerNo1
                    select new Promotion() {Code=p.Code,BrokerName=b.Name}).ToList<Promotion>();
        }
```

Comment: What kind of Data-Access technology are you using? (E.g. EF + Linq-to-entities)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to display the generated SQL for the Linq statement.

```
ReachDirectDataContext RDdc = new ReachDirectDataContext(connString);

RDdc.Log = Console.Out;

return (from b in RDdc.BrokerNos
        from p in dc.Promotions     
        where p.Source == source && p.Broker == b.BrokerNo1
        select new Promotion() {Code=p.Code,BrokerName=b.Name}).ToList<Promotion>();
```

You can try the following to separate out the queries.

```
var promotions = from p in dc.Promotions
                 where p.Source == source
                 select p;

var brokers = from o in promotions
              join b in RDdc.BrokerNos on o.Broker equals b.BrokerNo1
              select new Promotion 
              {
                  Code = o.Code,
                  BrokerName = b.Name
              };
return brokers.ToList();
```

Comment: The log out said 'System.InvalidOperationException', but I don't see any syntax error here.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are able to select from both databases with SQL?  In SQL you will do a 3-part query (database.schema.table) executed in one database. Not sure what Linq will do.  You can try what I will add above in Edit.

Comment: @Leons  I tried your code, it comes out with an error "The query contains references to items defined on a different data context". Any idea?

Comment: Aaaa... Linq is saying that it does not like to query over multiple databases (at least not in this scenario).  In cases such as this I usually create a view in the database so that my queries are always in one database, allowing the database to make the connection.

Comment: I found the following: "Relationships that cross database lines are simply out of scope for the entity framework".  See more at this link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/cad06147-2168-4c20-ac23-98f32987b126/

Comment: @Leons  OK, man. I created a view across two database, and do the query on the entity of this view, it works. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Linq is very an efficient way to do the data stuff, but still not powerful enough to beat sql.

Answer (score 2):

Your linq statement looks fine.  To aid in debugging, I find it helpful to assign the linq query to a local variable, then return the local variable.  You can then set a breakpoint on the return statement, and when the debugger stops at the breakpoint, you can inspect the query local variable to see what's in it, interactively.  You can use the Locals window in VS, or the Immediate Window to surf around inside your app's variables and see what's going on.

In particular, double check that the inputs into your linq query are actually providing data.  Verify that RDdc.Brokernos is non-empty, and dc.Promotions, etc.  If these are empty, the result will be empty.  Track your bug "upstream".

Minor point:  You don't need to specify the type parameter on the .ToList() call in the select. The compiler will infer the type automagically.

Answer (score 0):

The double from looks suspicious to me.
(This is not the equivalent to SQL's JOIN statement, if that is what you were aiming for.)

If you can combine the contexts:

Try creating relationship between BrokerNos and Promotions in edmx and using navigation property in query.

For example:

```
var result = dc.Promotions.Where(p => p.Source == source).
    Select(p => new Promotion() {
        Code = p.Code,
        BrokerName = p.Broker.Name, // use new navigation property here
    });
```

If not (intersection will be done in memory, not on DB!!!:

```
var result1 = dc.Promotions.Where(p => p.Source == source).
    Select(p => new Promotion() {
        Code = p.Code,
        BrokerId = p.BrokerId, // add id property for intermediate results
    }).ToList();   

var result2 = RDdc.Brokers.ToList();

var finalResult = result1.Where(p => result2.Contains(b => b.BrokerId == p.BrokerId)).Select(p => new Promotion{
        Code = p.Code,
        BrokerName = result2.Single(b => b.BrokerId == p.BrokerId).Name,
    });
```

Comment: Are both dataContexts to same database server instance? - If so, perhaps create an edmx that uses them both and integrates them. Then open up a context to it. See this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/11/25/working-with-large-models-in-entity-framework-part-1.aspx

Comment: The BrokerName must be traced from another database table BrokerNo.Name

Comment: Yes, same database server but different database.

Comment: Then you can run SQL queries that access them both. Try creating a model that integrates the 2 separate models.